# Accessing DOM from DOMContentLoaded event?

Tags: jquery, dom, firefox-addon

Is there a way to access the DOM from the event fired by `DOMContentLoaded`?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);

var myExtension = {
  init: function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser
    if(appcontent)
      appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, true);
  },

  onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {
     //how to access to the DOM from aEvent??
  }, 
}
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the first line in `onPageLoad` on the page you linked to shows how:

```
var doc = aEvent.originalTarget; // doc is document that triggered "onload" event
```

This gives you the `document` element of the website.